# Store and Echo PHP with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, echo, shortcode

I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for WP which I really like, because it gives me the ability to add a whole bunch of custom meta boxes to individual pages within my site, and implementation within page templates is very straightforward. This is generally how I would use it with a template:

```
<?php if( get_field('FIELD-NAME-HERE') ): ?>
    <h6><?php the_field('FIELD-NAME-HERE'); ?></h6>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In this case, I have a field for my Contact Form 7 Shortcode, and I've turned formatting off for this field, so it should return exactly what is entered (ie. [contact-form-7 title="Contact Form"] ).

I know that I can use the do_shortcode(); to pull this shortcode into my page template, but I want to be able to populate that do_shortcode(); with the_field(); from above.

I've tried this:

```
<?php if( get_field('form_shortcode') ): ?>
    <?php echo do_shortcode("<?php the_field('form_shortcode'); ?>");?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And this:

```
<?php
var formCode = the_field('form_shortcode');
echo do_shortcode(formCode);
?>
```

I'm still pretty new to PHP, but I feel like I'm not too far off. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not far off. You need to use `get_field()` rather than `the_field()`: `the_field()` actually echoes out the content, so that's why it's not working as currently using it. It's the equivalent of trying to echo it twice.

Another thing to look out for is that you need to include the square brackets when using `do_shortcode()` **but since your code already includes them you don't need to worry about it in this instance**.

```
<?php if( get_field('form_shortcode') ): ?>
    <?php echo do_shortcode( get_field('form_shortcode') );?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: In this case get_field('form_shortcode') is returning the full shortode (including the brackets) so you can leave them in your example.

Comment: This isn't working either. It displays the shortcode in text format, but doesn't display the actual shortcode. I also tried this:

    <?php if( get_field('form_shortcode') ): ?>
        <?php
        $formCode = the_field('form_shortcode');
        echo do_shortcode($formCode);
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

But it also just returns a the shortcode in text.

Comment: Well spotted @vicente; I've updated the example. @Eric Wood Try now

Comment: I tried that as well, and now it's returning this: [contact-form-7 404 "Not Found"] - Here's what I'm inputting into that "form_shortcode" field: [contact-form-7 id="123" title="Join the Team"] - I've tried removing the id and the title individually to see if one would work without the other, but I'm still getting the 404

Comment: Can you double check the shortcode that you're entering in your ACF field is correct; it sounds like it's trying to point at a form that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah I've double-checked this, and it's still not working. If I paste that same shortcode into the content editor of that page, the form displays fine.

Comment: Ahh! It was the text-formatting on the actual field. I had it set to "No Formatting" but when I changed it back to the default "Convert HTML into Tags" it works! Thanks so much for this!